# How to find the curvature of a surface using directional length dilation?

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I've already figured out how to find the curvature of an $f(x,y)$ function at each point.

$$K=\frac{f_{xx}f_{yy}-f_{xy}^2}{(1+f_x^2+f_y^2)^2}.$$

Now I want to find out how to calculate curvature with $s$ where
$$s=\left<\sqrt{1+f_x^2}\Biggl|\frac{f_xf_y}{|f_xf_y|}\sqrt{1+f_y^2}\right>=\left<\sqrt{1+f_x^2},\frac{f_xf_y}{|f_xf_y|}\sqrt{1+f_y^2}\right>$$

$s$ is the extra space caused by the existence of a slope. Any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: What do the angle brackets mean? Is it the average along a curve? it seems like if you have all the derivatives you could just plug it in

Comment: Oh, allow me to try to explain it better. When you have a function which has a slope at an angle, if you were to measure the arc length at that point, the magnitude would be greatest in the direction of the angle. I used the brackets to break it up into the x and y components of the arc length. I also modified it to give some info on the directionality of the arc length. That's why there's that f_x*f_y/|f_x*f_y| part in front of the y-component. Also, I'm trying to solve this for scenarios where the f(x,y) function is unknown but s(the directional arc length) is known.

Comment: should there be a comma somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I was using | as a separator but it wasn't big enough. It's fixed now.

Comment: Are these suppose to be the $x,y$ components of a vector? If so, then it's convention to write $\mathbf{v} = \langle v_x, v_y \rangle$.

Comment: Yes. I will add a modification to the equation to make this clearer.